# How to create nested for loop in list comprehension with if condition?

Tags: python, list

I am trying below code in list comprehension I also tried below but I am stuck.

```
new_threshold=0.5
    for i in range(len(data['Name'])):
        for key,values in dct.items():
            prev_threshold = SequenceMatcher(isjunk=None, a=data['Processed_Name'][i], b='credit', autojunk=True).ratio()
            if prev_threshold > new_threshold:
                new_threshold = prev_threshold
```

I tried so far

```
flatten_matrix = [temp   for i in range(len(data['Name'])) for key,values in dct.items() if (temp:= SequenceMatcher(isjunk=None, a=data['Name'][i], b='credit', autojunk=True).ratio())]
```

Comment: That loop does not accumulate a list, so it isn't really appropriate to try to convert it to a list comprehension. List comprehensions aren't always the better options; especially when the original code goes against their intended use case.

Comment: Start from the inner most level of nesting and create a list comprehension, then pack the next one around. But in general, I would not write such a loop in one line. It usually make the code more complex without adding more value. Minimal lines of code is not a metric for high quality code.

Comment: Always prefer simplicity over *cool* one-liners

Comment: @Carcigenicate so basically thought behind using list comprehension was time complexity of code. can you give me some suggestion on that ? How can I do that ?

Comment: @sheel A comprehension will behave roughly the same as a full loop (in cases where a list comprehension is actually appropriate). For cases where you're accumulating a list, a comprehension is slightly faster iirc, but those gains would likely be negated in your case here due to the comprehension building up a list that you don't need.